# VBA, Excel Chart Axis Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have charts made from a pivot(as I choose different pivot filters the chart changes). Some of the values are quite large others are quite small, which makes the charts hard to read sometimes as the Y Values are static.

Does anyone have any Code to alter this Y axis each time I change the chart, my idea is that each chart will be more legible with a fixed y axis each time? Any suggestions so I do have clearer charts is welcome.

Here are examples of what I currently have? I want to make the Y axis charge per each chart if possible.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjBdZ.jpg

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAa5i.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = ###
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = ###
```

Replace ### with the value you want, or you can define the MaximumScale to be the max value show in the chart, or some reference to it.

Comment: Hi Kelly, how do i define the MaximumScale to be the max value in the chart? Would you be able to provide a more full code? I am having trouble running this.